# Создание UNIX времени PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите как создать UNIX время, у меня есть форма в ней выберается время от 00:00 до 23:00 (часы и  минуты) каждое в селект и отдельно, мне нужно что бы оно конвертировалось в UNIX время типо time(); как сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = "11/12/2011 14:28"; 
echo $stamp = strtotime($date) . "<br />";
```

Comment: А не подскажешь как узнать Число По дню недели date('w',time()) ?

Comment: а может наоборот день недели по числу?)))))

Comment: Можно и так, мне главное что бы было и то и то в селекте , цыкл )